# What are the number of possible ways to build up a certain path?

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, co.combinatorics

### What are the number of possible ways to build up a certain path?

I was working on a graph problem and was trying to find out in how many possible ways can you build/grow a given path. With building/growing a given path I mean selecting a random edge of the path and adding connected edges to it until the full path is grown. I was trying to find a general formula but can't seem to find one.

#### For example the path with edges = {1,2,3}

[Path with 3 edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ajkY.png)

I can start growing it from a random edge, so I have 3 possibilities in the first step: edge 1, 2 or 3:

- (1) If I picked edge 1 the path can only grow to 2 in the next step

  - (12) In the next step the path can only grow to edge 3

    - (123)
- (2) If I picked edge 2 the path can grow to edge 1 or 3 in the next step

  - (1) If I picked edge 1 the path can only grow to 3

    - (3)
  - (3) If I picked edge 2 the path can only grow to 1

    - (1)
- (3) If I picked edge 3 the path can only grow to 2 in the next step

  - (2) In the next step the path can only grow to edge 1

    - (1)

So there are $3 * (\frac{1}{3}*2 + \frac{2}{3}*1) = 4$ possible ways to grow this graph.

#### For example the path with edges = {1,2,3,4}

[Path with 4 edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmyIQ.png)

There are 8 different ways to grow this path, you can see it as a group of permutations or orderings with the restriction that for $\forall x, \exists y: index(y) < index(x) \wedge (x = y +1 \vee x = y -1)$

- 1234
- 2134
- 2314
- 2341
- 3214
- 3241
- 3421
- 4321

Does anyone know a general formula to calculate this for paths of any length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, the answer is $2^{n-1}$. Instead of "growing" think
of "shrinking". There only 2 ways to shrink a path from length $n$ to a path
of length $n-1$.

Another way to see it is this: 
To get it for length 5, take your 8 paths above and add a 5:
12345,
21345,
23145,
etc.

then, to get the other 8, add one to all the numbers, for example,
change 1234 to 2345 and then add a 1 at the end. So we get
23451,
32451,
34251,
etc.

Comment: I like the shrinking analogy, it is very clear. Thank you. I didn't expect the formula to be so simple.